# Send mail at the end of parallel SSIS jobs

Tags: ssis

I have a set of independent SSIS packages say A,B,C. I'm running them manually and in parallel using DTEXEC command. Finishing time of these jobs can be random i.e, there is no certainty that only a particular job finishes last every time.

Now I want to send a notification mail when all the packages are completed. How can I accomplish this without modifying the packages? Also I may not be able to use task scheduler or SQL agent.

Comment: When you say "without modifying the packages," is this just by preference, or is modifying them really not an option? Likewise, you say you "may not" be able to use task scheduler or SQL Agent - can you use them or not? Once the options are clearer I'll gladly give you some suggestions, but I don't want to end up coming up with a solution which is either not usable for you, or is needlessly complex when you do have access to do it in a simpler way.

Comment: @JoDouglass : Sorry for late reply and thanks for your time and interest. I solved the problem by creating a master package which runs other independent packages in parallel and sends an email when all packages are completed.